# Pull Data between dynamic date range

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the query, where `sf.flex_start_date` & `sf.flex_end_date` is variable for `mis.seller_org_id`. Need help to get the data for the `seller_org_id` for that particular `date range` only. i.e data for seller should only be available after it's a `start date` and before it's `end date` (the data is available for before start date and after end date as well, but need data between that date range and this range is different for different `seller_org_id`).

Can anyone help ?

```
SELECT mis.order_id
    ,mis.order_status
    ,mis.seller_org_id
    ,mis.category
    ,mis.order_date
    ,log.rts_date
    ,log.picked_up_time
    ,sf.seller_name
    ,sf.parent_seller_org_id
    ,sf.parent_seller_name
    ,sf.seller_zone
    ,sf.seller_city
    ,sf.flex_supervisor_name
    ,sf.flex_start_date
    ,sf.flex_end_date
    ,sf.flex_status
FROM common.mis_table mis
LEFT JOIN logistics.logistics_data_full log ON mis.order_id = log.seller_order_id
LEFT JOIN ds_csv_seller_flex_seller_list sf ON mis.seller_org_id = sf.seller_org_id
WHERE mis.category NOT IN (
        'Food-FMCG'
        ,'Pharma'
        ,'Fullfilment Material'
        ,'Meat'
        ,'Fresh'
        )
    AND mis.fulfillment_center = 'FFC_SELLER'
    AND mis.order_date >= '2020-07-01'
    AND mis.order_date BETWEEN sf.flex_start_date
        AND sf.flex_end_date
```

Comment: Is this getting in the way `and mis.order_date >= '2020-07-01'`

Comment: Your `and mis.order_date between sf.flex_start_date and sf.flex_end_date` converts your `left join ds_csv_seller_flex_seller_list sf` to INNER JOIN.

Comment: @RiggsFolly
 Data is coming after that date only, but the range for different seller_org_id is not followed (For example, a seller's end date was in April, but still the data for July month is being pulled)

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause is turning your `left join` into an inner join.  With `left join`s all conditions on the first table should be in the `where` clause.  Any conditions on subsequent tables should be in the `on` clause:

```
select . . .
from common.mis_table mis left join
     logistics.logistics_data_full log
     on mis.order_id = log.seller_order_id left join
     ds_csv_seller_flex_seller_list sf
     on mis.seller_org_id = sf.seller_org_id and
     mis.order_date between sf.flex_start_date and sf.flex_end_date
where mis.category not in ('Food-FMCG', 'Pharma', 'Fullfilment Material', 'Meat', 'Fresh') 
      mis.fulfillment_center = 'FFC_SELLER' and
      mis.order_date >= '2020-07-01'
```

What happens in your query is that the `left join` might return `NULL` for non-matching rows -- or, more likely, there are matches but all the date range values are out of the range you want.  In either case, the `where` clause filters out the values.